# passing values from model to view in CI

Tags: class, codeigniter, model, view

I have this library in CI that retrieves my latest twitter updates. It has a function that sends my latest updates as objects to my controller.

I would like to show these twitter updates on the footer of my page, so they're visible at all times.

Now my question is how I call these directly from a view? I know this is not a good practice in MVC but I don't see how else I could do this.
My controller currently takes care of all my different pages (it's a small website) and I don't think it's very good practice to call my twitter class at the end of every page-function in the controller and then send it through to the views.

Typycally I do this in my controller:

```
<?php
    function index(){
    $data['page'] = 'home';
    //i don't want to call my twitter class here every single time I write a new page. (DRY?!)
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
?>
```

And it loads the "template" view that looks like this:

```
<?php
$this->load->view('header');

$this->load->view('pages/'.$page);

$this->load->view('footer');
?>
```

So any suggestions how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a helper library that takes a page Partial and wraps it in the master theme. You can use the optional parameter on your `load->view` to render to a string.

Then when you render your master page, you can load the twitter updates, and display them. Although, I highly suggest caching your twitter response for 5 minutes at least, will save you a LOT of overhead.

Example:

```
// Controller somwhere:
$content = $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, array(), true);
$this->myLibrary->masterPage($content);


// Your library:
function masterPage($content)
{

    $twitterData = $this->twitter->loadStuff(); // whatever your function is

    $twitter = $this->load->view('twitter_bar', array('data' => $twitterData), true);

    $this->load->view('master', array('content' => $content, 'twitter' => $twitter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did it this way. Having a helper that loads the view is a nice idea.

Comment: :) Thanks, glad I could help. I never understood why a master-page idea was never baked into CI. Always boggled my mind.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use a base controller. All my controllers extend my custom base controller which holds things I need on every page, for example an object containing the current user.